# Swift issue: About Type Casting for AnyObject

Tags: swift

Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific types:

AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

according official document: reference above and thinking about below case

```
class Person {
   var name = "new name"

   init(name: String) {
       self.name = name  
   }
}

var people: [AnyObject] = [Person(name: "Allen"), Person(name: "Hank"), 23]
```

Why? I can add 23 (`Int` is a struct) into `people` array?

Comment: What error do you get? looks like you have a few unmatched parens and typos..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little confusing because of the bridging that Swift does to Objective-C, where most things are classes and there are fewer value-types. To see what Swift does *without* the bridge, create a new playground and delete the `import ...` statement at the top, then try casting an `Int` to `Any` (no problem) and `AnyObject`:

```
let num = 23                               // 23
let anyNum: Any = num                      // 23
let anyObjectNum: AnyObject = num
// error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Now add `import Foundation` at the top of your playground:

```
import Foundation

let num = 23                               // 23
let anyNum: Any = num                      // 23
let anyObjectNum: AnyObject = num          // 23
```

The error goes away - why? When it sees the attempt to cast an `Int` to `AnyObject`, Swift first bridges `num` to be an instance of the Objective-C `NSNumber` class, found in `Foundation`, then casts it to the desired `AnyObject`. The same thing is happening in your array.

You can more or less prove this is the case using the `is` keyword - since `NSNumber` bridges to *all* the numeric types in Swift, it returns `true` in some funny cases:

```
anyNum is Int                              // true
anyNum is Double                           // false
anyObjectNum is Int                        // true
anyObjectNum is UInt                       // true
anyObjectNum is Double                     // true
anyObjectNum is Float                      // true
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why adding Foundation causes this weird behaviour!